# Trying to find duplicates using CTE in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, common-table-expression

I'm trying to modify the code I found below to allow me to find duplicates that I can delete for rows with RowOrder > 1.  I'm getting an error stating Incorrect syntax near ')' on the last line.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, please help.  Thanks in advance!

[original source](http://odetodata.com/2015/08/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-table-in-sql-server/)

```
WITH OrderedRows
AS
(
SELECT  ID, Carrier, ClaimDate, EmpID, ClaimNumber, LossNumber, TaskID, 
TaskType, TaskGroup, LetterDetails, Outlier, BeginTime, 
EndTime,TemplateUsed, Increment, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Carrier, 
ClaimDate, EmpID, ClaimNumber,LossNumber, TaskID, TaskType, TaskGroup, 
LetterDetails, Outlier, BeginTime, EndTime,TemplateUsed, Increment ORDER BY 
ID) as RowOrder
FROM    BillingStaging
)
DELETE FROM OrderedRows
WHERE RowOrder > 1
```

Comment: Looks like you may have left out the part where you SELECT/DELETE/ETC... from your CTE.  Stick `SELECT * FROM OrderedRows;` At the end of that statement.

Answer (score 4):

You just defined the CTE but you're not using it, you need to add the `delete` `from` statement

```
WITH OrderedRows
AS
(
     SELECT  ID, Carrier, ClaimDate, EmpID, ClaimNumber, LossNumber, TaskID, 
     TaskType, TaskGroup, LetterDetails, Outlier, BeginTime, 
     EndTime,TemplateUsed, Increment, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Carrier, ClaimDate, EmpID,ClaimNumber,LossNumber, TaskID, TaskType, TaskGroup,LetterDetails, Outlier, BeginTime, EndTime,TemplateUsed, Increment ORDER BY ID) as RowOrder
 FROM    BillingStaging
)
DELETE FROM OrderedRows
WHERE RowOrder > 1
```

Comment: I'm getting errors with the part I posted.  It doesn't make it to the delete statement.  I didn't include that line but should have to reduce confusion.  Can you see anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Do you have SQL statements prior to the CTE definition? If so then add ; before the WITH. another thing, do you really need to partition by so many columns? to identify duplicates?

Comment: This will eventually be in a stored procedure, but I'm trying to get the query right in the query editor first.  I tried it with a much smaller set of columns, but received the same error.  I see some examples that have the set of columns in parentheses after the WITH CTE.  I tried that too, but it didn't work.  Should I post that smaller set of columns?  I'm not sure if the indentation thing works in comments.

Comment: It is not related to indentation, just add a semicolon before the the CTE definition. e.g. ; WITH OrederedRows as (.....) delete from OrderedRows where RowOrder > 1.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. Figured it out. Original answer was correct. I was trying to get the syntax correct before using the `DELETE` statement, but by putting `SELECT * FROM OrderedRows`, it worked. Thanks for the help. It's been a while since I've done this.

This worked

```
WITH OrderedRows 
AS
(
SELECT
    ID, ClaimDate, EmpID, ClaimNumber, TaskType, BeginTime, EndTime, Increment,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ClaimDate, EmpID, ClaimNumber, TaskType, BeginTime,
        EndTime, Increment ORDER BY ID) as RowOrder
FROM BillingStaging
)
SELECT * FROM OrderedRows
```